# Мне надо чтобы несколько input вывело в одну строку. Как мне сделать чтобы я вводил эти два инпута в одной строке?

Tags: python, input

Например

```
a = input("Введите ваш пример: ")

b = input ("")

c = a + b 

print ("Ответ: ", c)
```

Comment: так и делай - вводи в одной строке, а потом разделяй на два числа

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = map(int, input("Введите ваш пример: ").split())
```

но учитывая, что пользователь может ввести и больше и меньше, то я бы сделал так:

```
a, b = (list(map(int, input("Введите ваш пример: ").split())) + [0, 0])[:2]
```

т.е. добавил бы и значения по умолчанию - `[0, 0]` и выборку только 2х значений из списка с большим кол-вом значений - `[:2]`